# Combining two count queries to produce a breakdown of both categories

Tags: mysql

I have a database with categories which include *system* and *status*. I can run the following to get a breakdown for either category :

```
SELECT status, count(*) FROM table GROUP BY status;
```

and the same for system.

What I need is a single query to show me how the count is distributed over *both* categories

So my result should have columns for each system, rows for each status and then a count in each field.

eg.

```
          SOMESYSTEM ANOTHERSYSTEM 
INERROR        5          6
OK             2          1
```

If anyone better at SQL than me could point me in the right direction, with some key words I can read up on, so I can crack this I'd be really grateful.

Comment: Can you give an example of the desired output? I'm not sure I completely follow what you're saying.

Comment: Read up on pivot tables. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table